# Get tiles count for shapefile in specified zoom level

Tags: shapefile, tiles, tile-map-service, count

I have polygonal shapefile, which contains several thousands of features. I need count tiles for 18 zoom level which generates for each feature in shapefile.
I find Tile Calculator http://tools.geofabrik.de/calc/#2/28.5307/62.5469&type=Geofabrik_Standard, but there possible get count tiles for one rectangle area (in shapefile this areas many).

How can I calculate the number of tiles for the shapefile at a certain zoom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find simple solution: plugin TileCover for QGIS

run plugin:

[image: run plugin]

select zoom level:

[image: select zoom level]

result:

[image: result]

Then needed features selected via spatial query.